# Hiding part of the URL using nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, ubuntu-14.04, reverse-proxy, nginx-location

In Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, how could we setup a nginx configuration fulfills both the two criteria from the user and the app below?

### [from the viewpoint of the user]

Accessing

```
https://example.com/
https://example.com/something
https://example.com/something/happens
```

will actually access:

```
https://example.com/app
https://example.com/app/something
https://example.com/app/something/happens
```

But we would like the browser url-field to show:

```
https://example.com/
https://example.com/something
https://example.com/something/happens
```

### [from the viewpoint of the app]

The app needs to use these links, with ***/app/*** as part of the link:

```
https://example.com/app
https://example.com/app/something
https://example.com/app/something/happens
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) directive is what you're looking for:

```
location / {
    try_files app$uri;
}
```

However if you use absolute url's in your application this won't work, because [try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) doesn't change the url's in the response.